# Problems with a questionnaire cloned

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, checkbox, checkboxlist

I´m doing a questionnaire that can be clone using Jquery `.clone()`. I´m using checkboxes to answer the questions using yes or no. My questionnaire is inside a table and then using this code:

```
  $(':checkbox').on('change',function(){
        var tr = $(this), name = tr.prop('name');

        if(tr.is(':checked')){
            $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
        }
```

I can check only one checkbox in the same row(tr), but the problem is when I clone the questionnaire using a button. The script is working for the first questionnaire, but not for the second. When is cloned is generated a new id (previous_id_2).

I tried many things but I think that the script is not the most suitable for my code, because only works with the first. I need something that works as follows:

```
If two checkboxes in same row -> only be able to select one. 

>And something that should be works for different div id, because it´s generated
 a new id for each table, the structure of the html is:
 <div id="questionnaire {{ number }}">
 <table class="table quest">
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td><checkbox 1 id="q_Q1_y{{ number }}" name="q_Q1_y{{ number }}" class="table quest yes" ></td>
 <td><checkbox 2 id="q_Q1_n{{ number }}" name="q_Q1_n{{ number }}" class="table quest"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><checkbox 1 id="q_Q2_y{{ number }}" name="q_Q1_y{{ number }}" class="table quest yes"></td>
 <td><checkbox 2 id="q_Q2_n{{ number }}" name="q_Q2_n{{ number }}" class="table quest"></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

number shows the number of repetitions that you have.I know that radio buttons are most suitable for this, but I need do it suing checkboxes. I think the script should not be more complicated than I did.

Comment: this isn't complete enough to answer - can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), and is there an error with the cloned one? What happens when you try and select 2 from the same row? Can you select all options or none, or do the options affect the first questionnaire as well? I think the code around the button will be needed,

Comment: I´m using Laravel, so it´s complicated to create there, but the main question is how to avoid duplicate the values of the radiobuttons. Because in clone functions the name/id is concatenated with a value as _2, _3 or whatever. But there I have to find the way to clean the values of the radiobuttons, but only for the new group generated.

Answer (score 0):

why use `<checkbox>` for yes and no? If both can't be checked you should be using **radiobuttons** - or is your `<checkbox>` tag actually a radio button? You also reference CSS which is not here. 
Code posted here should be [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - going through that process helps you become a better programmer. You might need to adapt the problem into a form you can post via jsfiddle, which allows jquery libraries.